# How to connect wired xbox 360 controller to a tablet? (TF Prime)

Tags: usb, game-controllers

I have read on certain blogs that it is super easy to connect a wired xbox controller to an android tablet. It should basically work right away.

I have tried to connect multiple xbox controller to my TF prime, but the apps that are supposed to support them, seem to do nothing.
Also, the controller does not show up in the droids "input and language" settings. (allthough I'm not sure wether it is supposed to)

Has anyone got this to work? Or have a clue as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does your USB adapter work with normal USB keyboards or any other devices?  It could be the faulty link.

Comment: @John I have just tried to connect my mac usb keyboard. It did not show up in "input and languages" settings, but it did work in the browser. All I did was connect it. Got no indicator on the TF Prime that showed the keyboard connected. But it did work well.

Comment: See also: [Trying to use Xbox controller on Nexus 7](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35872/)

Comment: it may be because u dont have genuine microsoft xbox 360 controller because i have the same problem but i have a powerA mini controller and i have found that this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there are two types of Xbox360 controller.

1. the regular wireless controller (with optional usb-charger cable)
2. the actual wired usb controller

Allthough the wireless controller with USB charger cable looks like a regular USB controller, it does not behave this way. Also when connected via USB it will still operate wirelessly.

So the problem lies in the controller. To use a xbox360 controller via USB, we would need the actual wired USB controller and *NOT* the wireless controller with charger cable.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just plug the controller in to your tablet with a OTG usb cable and then  an app like [USB/BT Joystick Center 6](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.poke64738.usbjoy) will map the controller inputs to something your device can recognise.