# Trying to use Xbox controller on Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, game-controllers

I just got the Asus Nexus 7 and I am attempting to play the N64 emulator (Mupen64 plus, AE). I have my wired xbox 360 controller plugged in to the otg cable, but the light does not stay on the controller and the Nexus is not reading it. Only when I press it does it flash for a second. Help?

Comment: Have you tried the controller with other games besides N64 emulator games?

Answer (score 1):

This very comprehensive article entitled **"Guide to Game Controllers on Android"** published on 9th May 2012 maybe greatly beneficial to you:

http://www.pocketables.com/2012/05/guide-to-game-controllers-on-android.html

You may also be interested in this video (approx.45 mins duration) entitled "Gaming On The Nexus 7 With A PS3 Controller"

http://revision3.com/hak5/how-to-bluetooth-a-controller-to-nexus

Comment: How can the PS3 controller video help?

Comment: @Matthew Read: Principle of connecting the controller to the Nexus 7 is the same

Comment: Is it?  He's not using a Bluetooth controller.

Comment: @Matthew Read Thats true, in hindsight I thought it might be helpful to him